# attempt to call global 'lapp' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, pycharm

I'm working on mac and run lua with Pycharm IDE.
When running lua script on Pycharm with the following params: [image]

My code start with:

```
require('mobdebug').start()
require 'xlua'
require 'optim'
require 'cunn'
require 'loadcaffe'
dofile './provider256.lua'
local c = require 'trepl.colorize'
local lfs = require 'lfs'

opt = lapp[[
   -s,--save                  (default "logs/nin")      subdirectory to save logs
   -b,--batchSize             (default 50)          batch size
   -r,--learningRate          (default 0.01)        learning rate
   --learningRateDecay        (default 1e-7)      learning rate decay
   --weightDecay              (default 0.0005)      weightDecay
   -m,--momentum              (default 0.9)         momentum
   --epoch_step               (default 33)          epoch step
   --model                    (default nin)     model name
   --max_epoch                (default 100)           maximum number of iterations
   --data_loc                 (default "workspace/dataset/torch")            image location
   --trainData                (default "workspace/dataset/torch/train.txt")  train.txt location
   --testData                 (default "workspace/dataset/torch/val.txt")    val.txt location
   --image_size               (default 256)         image size
   --crop_size                (default 224)         image size after crop
   --use_pretrained           (default false)   whether to use pre-trained model
   --num_labels               (default 1000)    number of labels
   --do_aug                   (default false)   do augmentation or not
   --max_label                (default -1)      label with maximum occurences to subsample
   --max_2max_ratio           (default -1)      ratio of maximum label to subsample and 2nd maximum label
   --pretrained_model_loc     (default none)    location of the pre-trained model
]]

print(opt)
print(lfs.currentdir())
```

And I got error:

```
/imcnn/train256.lua:31: attempt to call global 'lapp' (a nil value)
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear.

This happens because `lapp` is a `nil` value and you attempt to call it in line 31.

`lapp` must be a global function if you want to call it in the global scope.

You most likely forgot to require something here.

A quick websearch suggests that lapp is part of the penlight library.

I found an example with the line `lapp = require 'pl.lapp'`
Adding this line in front of the lapp call might fix your problem.